# Babel, tikz and Beamer do not work together

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, babel

The following code fails to build with the message

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
```

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,unknownkeysallowed,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,babel,calc,angles,quotes}
\usepackage{tikzsymbols}
\begin{document}
\section{Figura}
\begin{frame}
         TiKz   \pgfversion
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick]
(3,-1) coordinate (a) node[right] {a} -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {b} 
-- (2,2) coordinate (c) node[above right] {c} pic["$\alpha$", thick,draw=orange, <->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm] {angle=a--b--c};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, it works if brazil babel line is commented or if the tikzpicture is built out of a frame. `\pgfversion` shows 3.0.0.

Comment: Did you try `\begin{frame}[fragile]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanism provided by the `babel` TikZ library consists in changing the category code of `"` upon starting a `tikzpicture`. Essentially, it is equivalent to adding `\shorthandoff{"}` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`.

Unfortunately, this can't work in a Beamer `frame`, because the contents of the frame is absorbed before processing, so character tokens get their category code, which no `\shorthandoff{"}` command can change any longer.

Workaround (a bit ugly, I know): use `\begin{frame}[fragile]`, which makes Beamer write out the contents of the frame for later rereading.

Watch out that `\end{frame}`, in this case, ***must*** start without any preceding space at the leftmost column.